# how to prepend/append addtional values with default values of groupText of jqgrid grouping?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using Non-Commercial version of `Guriddo JS jqgrid`. [Also I tried the same using `"free jqgrid"` as well,  it didn't work,and I don't know how to do it.] I am using grouping method.

on the grouped row, I am seeing a number value like `276` , `155` like that. But what I want to see is, `Group:#276` or `Group:#155 - someTextToappend` like this.

I order to achieve this, I am using a custom formatter in the `colModel` like,
`{name:"ticket_id",index:"ticket_id",align:"right",formatter:taskTextFormat`

I have a function as follows,

```
function taskTextFormat(cellvalue,options,rowObject){ 
     // I am returning a string concatenated value something like
    return "Group:#"+rowObect["task_ID"];
    }
```

and I have set groupingField to that column `ticket_id` so this function is triggered and values are returned but I am seeing same text over all the grouped rows. like,

```
Group:#276 // row one
Group:#276 // row two , I think the last groupText value is reflected on all other grouped rows as well.
```

Instead, what I wanted is,

```
Group:#276 // row one
Group:#277 // row two
Group:#278 // row three and so on.
```

Please help me on this, I am not sure this is the right way to do this, if there is a better way I would be happy to use that.

Comment: Please use *correct* tags to your questions. You used "free-jqgrid" tag. You can click on the tag and then click on "learn more…" to see [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info) that "free jqGrid" is the name of the product. On the other side you write, that you use ["Guriddo jqGrid JS"](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) and name it "Non-Commercial", which is misunderstandable for other readers. I'm not sure that you get some special Non-Commercial version. In any way, it's important to include **version number** of the product.

Comment: @Oleg, really sorry, I got your free-jqgrid from [https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid] also, from the Guriddo site, exactly from the link [http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102663] , I clicked on the "Learn more" of first product `Guriddo jqGrid JS` there in that page I have read the licensing terms ,  I clicked "Download" and it lead to another page with a download button there I got the Guriddo jqgrid 5.2.2. And I am not selling it to anybody I am just using in my project. If this is a license violation , I am ready to delete all the Guriddo thing. Please let me know if I am violating the terms.

Comment: "free jqGrid" (https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) has no relation to Guriddo, which is **alternative** product. You can click on "Cone and download" button, on https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases or you can use it from CDN directly (see https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html and [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). Please read [README](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) too, which describes npm, Nuget and other sources.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean Trial version of Guriddo jqGrid JS?

[Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://www.guriddo.net) is commercial and it is free only for:

- A student, university or a public school
- A non-profit organisation
- Developing and testing application

To solve the problem you need to read some [documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/grouping/#data-grouping)
What you need is a groupText option - read it.

[Demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/multiple_columns_header/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response! Please look at my reply to Oleg's comment. In case if you feel I am violating the license, please let me know. I am always ready to delete the content. It was mentioned at [http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102666] as `If you want to use Guriddo jqGrid JS for a **personal website** or a non-profit organisation, you don’t need the author’s permission, just go on and use Guriddo jqGrid JS. For commercial websites and projects, see License and Pricing. `  May be I misunderstood that "personal website" term. If I am wrong , sorry I delete your content fully.

Comment: Not a problem. Everthing is OK and I hope the the problem with the grouping  is solved.

Comment: Thank you Tony. Coming to the groupText problem, I have seen your demo, that is really okay if the prefix and suffix are constant texts. In my case, Prefix  strings are dynamically generated , nothing but value of one of the property in the `rowObject` object.my function "taskTextFormat" is called for the content row (the inner one) once and the grouped row (the one which holds the groupText) once. so , in the first call it works well and returns expected result. But in the second call that property doesn't exist in rowObject and somehow all the groupTexts get the last groupText's text.

Comment: I think the best way to see what you do is to publish your code and demo data. You can use jsfiddle for this purpose

Comment: in jsfiddle, I can't attach Guriddo js right? sorry, I never used jsfiddle. Let me try it out.

Comment: @Oleg, for a sample [ https://jsfiddle.net/92da8xhq/1/ ] I have taken your example and forked it. So here is the fiddle, [ https://jsfiddle.net/4aojr87w/ ] , In that, notice the `formatter:clientFormatter` and the function at the bottom. that's what I am trying to do. Basically what am I trying is, with the default groupText trying to append some dynamic content (from the `rowData`). If this is not the right way please help me, how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: you use *custom formatter* in the demo https://jsfiddle.net/4aojr87w/ to format the first column. The formatter will be used *not only for formatting of data*, but for formatting of the group header too. You can test the type of `rowData` or `options.rowData` to detect, whether the row of data or the group header heed be formatted. The `rowData` parameter (or `options.rowData`) will be object with `amount` property only in case of formatting the data. Thus you have to change the code of `clientFormatter` to, for example, the following

```
function clientFormatter(cellvalue,options,rowData)
{
    if (typeof rowData === "object") {
        console.log(rowData.amount);
        return cellvalue + " " + rowData.amount;
    } else {
        // formatting for the group header
        return "Group: " + cellvalue + "!!!"
    }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4aojr87w/1/